# External SSD stopped being recognized - is it dead?

Tags: mount, ssd, external-hdd, lsusb

I have an external SSD drive that I use for backup, plugged into a Raspberry Pi and always on. After a couple of forced reboots (problem with the Raspberry Pi power source), the external SSD stopped being recognized. The external SSD indicator light turns on. But the drive is not mounted. Neither `lsusb` od `dmesg` shows anything. I plugged the SSD in another computer and again, SSD is not listed in `lsusb` or `dmesg`.
Also, Gnome disk utility does not see the drive.

*Is it dead? Have I got a paperweight?*

Comment: if you don't see *anything* in `dmesg` resp. `lsusb` then you either blew the USB-controller of your disk, or something more mundane like a broken USB-cable... do other things work on the same USB-port (of the RPi) with the same cable?

Comment: did you try to take out the actual ssd of the usb case and cinnect it with a sata cable to a pc?

Comment: The USB port is fine. I connected other things and it works. I tried another cable and it did not work. I'll take the disk back to the manufacture (Samnsung) and see if they can do something. If they can't fix it, I'll try to open the case and connect the SSD using a new USB-controler.